# Making a bus-stop diagram with css - problem when sliding image along the edge

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a bus stop diagram for a webpage I'm making. Searching online I was already able to make and style it from a list, but know I'm trying to add some bus icons that can be moved vertically along the edge to show where the bus is located.
I'm expecting to put some icons to the side, that can be moved from top to bottom, with the top being 0% and the bottom being 100%, as I have a JS code that receives this value.
I've been searching quite a bit, but I was unable to make it work.

I tried making a container to the side of the inner div with flexbox, but the icon goes out of the page.
Also I expect to be able to have several icons on top of each other. They can overlap, but the only condition is that they have to be vertically aligned, and all move relative the container and not to each other.

Here I have a simplified version of the code and styles that generate the list:

```css
.diagrama-linea {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.diagrama-dentro {
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.paradas-linea {
  list-style: none;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-color: var(--color-linea);
  padding-left: 1em;
  margin-left: 4em;
}

.parada::before {
  content: '';
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: var(--color-linea);
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: -1.55em;
}

.parada p {
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.simbolo_linea {
  padding: 2px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white!important;
}

.simbolo_linea,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="diagrama-linea">
  <div class="marca-bus"><img src="bus.png">
    <p><small>bus 999</small></div>
  <div class="diagrama-dentro">
    <ol class="paradas-linea" style="--color-linea: #019F02">
      <li class="parada"><span class="nombre_parada">Stop 1</span>
        <p><a href="#">Enlaces:</a> <span class="simbolo_linea" style="background-color: #C0910F">3</span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="parada"><span class="nombre_parada">Stop 2</span>
        <p><a href="#">Enlaces:</a> <span class="simbolo_linea" style="background-color: #C0910F">3</span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="parada"><span class="nombre_parada">Stop 3</span>
        <p><a href="#">Enlaces:</a> <span class="simbolo_linea" style="background-color: #C0910F">3</span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="parada"><span class="nombre_parada">Stop 4</span>
        <p><a href="#">Enlaces:</a> <span class="simbolo_linea" style="background-color: #C0910F">3</span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="parada"><span class="nombre_parada">Stop 5</span>
        <p><a href="#">Enlaces:</a> <span class="simbolo_linea" style="background-color: #C0910F">3</span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="parada"><span class="nombre_parada">Stop 6</span>
        <p><a href="#">Enlaces:</a> <span class="simbolo_linea" style="background-color: #C0910F">3</span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="parada"><span class="nombre_parada">Stop 7</span>
        <p><a href="#">Enlaces:</a> <span class="simbolo_linea" style="background-color: #C0910F">3</span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="parada"><span class="nombre_parada">Stop 8</span>
        <p><a href="#">Enlaces:</a> <span class="simbolo_linea" style="background-color: #019F02">12</span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="parada"><span class="nombre_parada">Stop 9</span>
        <p><a href="#">Enlaces:</a> <span class="simbolo_linea" style="background-color: #019F02">12</span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="parada"><span class="nombre_parada">Stop 10</span>
        <p><a href="#">Enlaces:</a> <span class="simbolo_linea" style="background-color: #019F02">12</span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="parada"><span class="nombre_parada">Stop 11</span>
        <p><a href="#">Enlaces:</a> <span class="simbolo_linea" style="background-color: #019F02">12</span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="parada"><span class="nombre_parada">Stop 12</span>
        <p><a href="#">Enlaces:</a> <span class="simbolo_linea" style="background-color: #F94F8E">11</span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="parada"><span class="nombre_parada">Stop 13</span>
        <p><a href="#">Enlaces:</a> <span class="simbolo_linea" style="background-color: #019F02">12</span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="parada"><span class="nombre_parada">Stop 14</span>
        <p><a href="#">Enlaces:</a> <span class="simbolo_linea" style="background-color: #00B17A">4</span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="parada"><span class="nombre_parada">Stop 15</span>
        <p><a href="#">Enlaces:</a> <span class="simbolo_linea" style="background-color: #FDB515">2</span></p>
      </li>
      <li class="parada"><span class="nombre_parada">Stop 16</span>
        <p><a href="#">Enlaces:</a> <span class="simbolo_linea" style="background-color: #FDB515">2</span></p>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'll add an image that shows the expected result [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAFTR.png):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what I wanted to do, what I had to do is put the image inside the flex div at the same level as the container of the diagram.
With js, and knowing its id, I can modify their `margin-top` property, and by knowing the total height of the container and the percentage that I want to position them at, after applying some margins, I can just move it with JS, here is an snippet of how to do that:

```
const height = document.getElementById('ida').offsetHeight; // get the container's height
const x = 80*height/100; // 80 would be the percentage value
document.getElementById('buses-ida').innerHTML += '<div style="margin-top: '+x+'px; position: absolute"><span class="material-symbols-outlined simbolo_bus simbolo_bus_parada">directions_bus</span></div>';
```

Comment: if you share the full solution it could be helpful for the others.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).